# Disable Mouse Wheel Scaling using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am using npm package `react-flow-chart` in a project,

The chart has inbuilt property that it scales up and down with mouse wheel.

Is there any way I can `disable this mouse-scaling using a CSS property` ?

Thanks in Advance.

Post Note: I have seperate buttons to scale the chart in a predefined range, solution should not affect that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside your `<head>` in `index.html`

```
<meta 
     name='viewport' 
     content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' 
/>
```

Comment: Actually, I am not allowed to add meta tags, I need a way that can be simply implemented via a CSS class. @Michal Lach

Answer (score 1):

With CSS not possible.

you can added it using js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("head").append(
    "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'/>"
  );
});
```